# Counting lines from specific line

Tags: linux

How to count the number of lines in a text file starting with a specific line. `wc -l` counts it all.

Comment: How do you decide which line is the start line  ? Via a line no. or via a pattern ?

Comment: Please explain your question a little more. As don_crissti mentioned, we need to know the condition under which counting should begin.

Comment: Take your specific line, compute `wc -l` and subtract?

Answer (score 1):

The `-v` argument for `nl` will modify where the counting starts.  If you want to start counting with 1 from the fifth line, you can use `nl -v -3 file`.  It will start at -3, and the fifth line with thereby be numbered 1.

Alternatively, if you just want to skip the first 5 lines of a file, you can combine `tail` and `nl`.  `tail -n+5 file | nl` will skip the first five lines, and number the rest of them, starting at one.

If you really wish to *count* the lines less a certain number, you can simply use `wc -l` to count the number of lines, and then do simple arithmetic:

```
lines="$(wc -l /path/to/file | awk '{print $1}')"; echo $(($lines-5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tail -n +`line from where you want to count to start` | wc -l
e.g.
tail  -n +2 /etc/passwd | wc -l. This will display the file from line 2 to the rest.